# MATLAB ANFIS sets MF parameters to 0

Tags: matlab, fuzzy

I'm using MATLAB ANFIS to train a FIS generated by FCM (using genfis3). The problem is that the resulting FISs (both the trained and validated ones) have all membership function parameters =0 (gaussian MF with centers and sigma's set to 0). This only happens with a specific data set I use. The FIS generated using genfis3 has normal (nonzero) MF parameters. Why does this happen? Is there a way to avoid it (like adjusting some ANFIS parameters or options)?

Edit:
Here is the code, it is simple

```
Gfismat = genfis3(TrnDataIn, TrnDataOut, 'sugeno', 2);

[fis,error,stepsize,chkFis,chkErr] = anfis([TrnDataIn TrnDataOut] ,Gfismat,[],[],[ValDataIn ValDataOut]);
```

When evaluating fis or chkFis I get the error:

```
Error using evalfismex
Illegal parameters in fisGaussianMF() --> sigma = 0
```

Inspecting fis and chkFis:

```
fis.input(1).mf.params
ans =

 0     0


ans =

 0     0
```

However, the fis generated using genfis3 has the following MF values:

```
Gfismat.input(1).mf.params

ans =

0.1542    0.3622


ans =

0.1111    0.3130
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, please include some of the code you are working with and a reproducible example others can work off of to try and help you.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, I have included some of the code and more detailed results.